# Can you place a logo over a background with two different colours?

Tags: logo

I created a design for our project and was going to place our stacked logo in between two colours that splits the logo into two, is that bad logo practice? For some information, the logo is like this:
[image: Triangular Logo]

This is how it will look like on the design (cropped):

[image: Triangular Design Test]

Answer is much appreciated as I have no contact with the logo designer at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: I think the logo could use some work. What do the shapes mean? Why does one have rounded borders? Why are pieces missing from the letters? Why is the name all caps? Then you can focus more on the background: what's the color palette here? Why are the edges angled the way that they are? Why is the logo being split like this in the first place? Lots of questions need to be answered

Comment: I think this is a matter of *opinion*. I, personally, would *never* change a logos appearance in the same manner as your sample. You *aren't* merely placing a background behind the logo, you are *changing the perception of the logo itself*. Logos should *not* be viewed as their individual pieces to be picked apart or divided. They should be viewed as one, singular object.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This question is really too opinion based.  My opinion FWIW: what you have done here is essentially redesign the logo.  It's not just a background change - the shapes you have made now look like they are part of the logo design.  If your remit is to redesign the logo, it might be OK. Depends entirely what you or the organisation want to do.